# cakephp 3.2 cant load css and js after install on ubuntu server

Tags: cakephp

how to solve this problem ? already install cake php on ubuntu server but css and JS cant load..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICSDK.jpg)

Comment: Make sure the webroot/css and webroot/js are readable by the webserver.

Comment: already readable ,but still cant load.. i install ubuntu server on vmware on mac n install cakephp on ubuntu server